# Not getting new data on scroll, its adding the same json data again and again on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I implemented load data on scroll, whihc add data on scroll. But it seems to be adding the same thing again and again on scroll.. its not gettign the next records/json.

How can i add new data to the existing data? Can someone show me some examples?

NOTE - no plugins .

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">

function myAJAXfun(event) {
var searchTerm = $("#search").val(); // get the user-entered search term
                    var URL = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne";
                    //var URL = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne";
                    var ID = "25053835@N03";
                    //var MYID-"84215563@N08";
                    //var tagmode="&tagmode=any";
                    //var format ="&format=json";
                    var tags="&tags="+ searchTerm;
                    var tagmode="&tagmode=any";
                    var jsonFormat = "&format=json&jsoncallback=?";                 
                    var ajaxURL= URL+"?jsoncallback=?id="+ID+tags+tagmode+jsonFormat;
                    //var ajaxURL= URL+"?"+tags+tagmode+jsonFormat;

                    $.getJSON(ajaxURL,function(data){
                    //$("h1").text(data.title);
                    //alert(data.length);

                    var photoHTML;
                     $("#photos").empty();  
                        if (data.items.length) {
                        //  alert(data.items.length);

                          $.each(data.items, function(i,photo) {

                            //var photoHTML = "<h4>" +photo.tags + "</h4>";
                            //photoHTML = "<p>";
                            photoHTML += '<a href="' + photo.link + '">';
                            photoHTML += '<img src="' + photo.media.m + '" alt="' + photo.media.m + '" title="' + photo.media.m + '"></a>';
                            //photoHTML = "</p>";
                            $('#photos').append(photoHTML).fadeIn(200);
                                                      });

                        } else {
                            alert(data.items.length);   
                             photoHTML = "<h2> No Results</h2>";
                             $('#photos').append(photoHTML).fadeIn(200);
                        }
                         //$('#photos').append(photoHTML).fadeIn(200);

                 });    
}
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#submit").click(function (event) {
    myAJAXfun();

 });

  $("#scrollbox").scroll(function(){
       myAJAXfun();
    });
});





</script>
<style type="text/css" >
    #container{ width:400px; margin:0px auto; padding:40px 0; }
    #scrollbox{ width:900px; height:450px;  overflow:auto; overflow-x:hidden; border:1px solid #f2f2f2; margin-top:150px;}
    #container > p{ background:#eee; color:#666; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:0.75em; padding:5px; margin:0; text-align:right;}
    #searchBar {align:center; position:fixed; height:150px; background-color:#777; border:1px solid red; width:100%;top:0;}
    #photos {} 
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div align="center" id="searchBar">
<h2>flicker tag search</h2>
<div>Enter Search Term</div>
<input type="text" id=search />
<input type="button" id=submit value="Search" />
</div> 
  <div id="container">
    <div id="scrollbox" >
<div id="photos"></div> 
    </div>
    <p><span id="status" ></span></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you are implementing this yourself, rather than using a plugin? Furthermore, you are using the Flickr feeds service, which really shouldn't be used for this type of thing, as it does not allow you to ``skip`` and ``take``, and will always return the same resultset.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you fetch data you must have a variable where you keep track of the information you fetched so far.

At every new call, pass this variable a parameter, like an offset, so in the server side you will know what page of results you have to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

Use $.ajax function with post method at the place of $.getJSON
hope your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you append it finally after `photoHTML` is completed

```
$.each(data.items, function(i,photo) {

        photoHTML += '<a href="' + photo.link + '">';
        photoHTML += '<img src="' + photo.media.m + '" alt="' + photo.media.m + '" title="' + photo.media.m + '"></a>';
        //photoHTML = "</p>";
});
//Append Now
$('#photos').append(photoHTML).fadeIn(200);
```

Comment: If you look at my code I am already appending it under if and else statement  $('#photos').append(photoHTML).fadeIn(200);

Comment: Yes. I can see that. I was pointing out to put the append outside the `$.each` callback function. And please provide a jsfiddle if you want faster solutions. If you have found a solution please do share it here.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to tell Flickr to send you the next load of photos, otherwise they will keep sending you the same ones over and over again. Also the Feed system only ever returns 20 photos.

Call and API method instead, and use the "page" parameter.